# Taylor expansion of composite functions

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, intuition, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose one has a function of the form: $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+a\cos^{2}(x)}$$ where $a$ is some parameter.

Firstly, what is the correct method for Taylor expanding such a composite function? Should one just repeatedly use the chain rule $(f\circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x)$ to determine the coefficients of the Taylor expansion, such that it has the form: $$(f\circ g)(x)=(f\circ g)(x_{0})+(f\circ g)'(x_{0})(x-x_{0})+\frac{1}{2}(f\circ g)''(x_{0})(x-x_{0})^{2}+\cdots$$ or is there a different method?

Secondly, although not technically a Taylor expansion, if the parameter $a<<1$ is it reasonable to approximate the function as $$\sqrt{1+a\cos^{2}(x)}\approx 1+\frac{a}{2}\cos^{2}(x)$$ i.e. naively plugging in $a\cos^{2}(x)$ to the Taylor expansion for $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{8}+\mathcal{O}(x^{3})$?

Comment: You cannot plug in $acos^2 (x)$ since it doesn't go to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your method would work, but it'd involve computing a lot of unpleasant derivatives.  A better method would be to expand $cos^2(x)$, then expand the square root:
$$\sqrt{1+a \cos^2(x)} = \sqrt{1 + a \left(1 - \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)\right)^2} \\
= \sqrt{1 + a \left(1 -  x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)\right)} \\
= \sqrt{1 + a -  a x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)} \\
= \sqrt{1+a} \sqrt{1 - \frac{a}{1+a} x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)} \\ 
= \sqrt{1+a} \left(1 - \frac{a}{2(1+a)} x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)\right) \\
= \sqrt{1+a} - \frac{a}{2\sqrt{1+a}} x^2 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)$$

Comment: Can one use this method in general for composite function? That is can one first Taylor expand the input function $g(x)$ and then insert it into the Taylor expansion of $f(y)$ with $y=g(x)$?

Comment: @Feyn_example You must have $\lim_0g (x)=0$

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Why is this required?

Comment: @Feyn_example i  will edit it now.

Comment: The method I describe here would work in general, but it's not expanding $f(y)$, but instead expanding the function you'd get after expanding $g(x)$. This sidesteps the problem that Salahamam describes, since we're expanding a function where $x$ is certainly 0.

Comment: @B.Mehta       Ah, so is this approach only valid if $g(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$? I'm not sure I entirely understand why $g(x)$ must tend to zero as $x\rightarrow 0$ in order for it to be valid?

Comment: Substituting $y=g(x)$ into the expansion of $f(y)$ is only valid for $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, because the expansion $f(y)$ is valid as $y \to 0$.  The approach I outlined doesn't substitute into the expansion of $f(y)$, but instead into $f$ itself, and then do an expansion in $x$ instead.

Comment: @B.Mehta       Is this the case even when the expansion for  $f(y)$ is valid for all $x$ (clearly in the specific case I gave the expansion is only valid in the neighbourhood of $y=0$ and has a radius of convergence $\lvert y\rvert <1$, but in other cases the radius of convergence may be $\inf$)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $f (X)=P_n(X)+X^n\epsilon_1 (X) $ and
$g (y)=Q_m (y)+y^m\epsilon_2 (y) $ then

$$f (g (y))=P_n (g (y))+g^n (y)\epsilon_1(Q_m(y)+y^m\epsilon_2 (y)) $$

when $y\to 0$, you need $Q_m (0)=0$ to satisfy $\epsilon_1\to 0$.

Starting from
$$\sqrt {1+X}=1+\frac X2-\frac {X^2}{8}+... $$

you can replace $X $ by $g (X) $ only if $\lim_{X\to 0}g (X)=0$.
which is not the case for $a\cos^2 (x) $ since it goes to $a $.

so you write your function as

$$\sqrt {1+a+a (\cos^2 (x)-1)}=$$
$$\sqrt {1+a}\sqrt {1+\frac {a(\cos^2 (x )-1)}{1+a} }$$
and now you can replace $X $ by
$$g (x)=\frac {a (\cos^2 (x)-1)}{1+a} .$$

Comment: Can one use this sort of method in general for composite functions? Also, would it be legitimate to approximate $\sqrt{1+a\cos^{2}(x)}\approx 1+\frac{a}{2}\cos^{2}(x)$ if $a<<1$?

Comment: Thanks for the further details. Would it not be approximately valid (at least to first-order) to replace $X$ with $a\cos^{2}(x)$ in the case where $a<<1$? I understand that as $X\rightarrow 0$ $g(X)$ will not be exactly zero, but it will be close to zero for small $a$, for example $a=10^{-7}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+a - a\sin^{2}(x)} = \sqrt{1+a}\sqrt{1 - {a\over a+1}\sin^2x}$$
$$ = \sqrt{1+a}\left(1 - {1\over2}{a\over a+1}\sin^2x  + {1\over2!}{1\over2}\left({1\over2}-1\right)\left(-{a\over a+1}\right)^2\sin^4x\right) +O(x^6)$$
$$ = \sqrt{1+a}\left(1 - {1\over4}{a\over a+1}(1-\cos2x) - {1\over32}{a^2\over (a+1)^2}(1-2\cos 2x+\cos^22x)\right)+O(x^6)$$
$$ = \sqrt{1+a}\left(1 - {1\over4}{a\over a+1}(1-\cos2x) - {1\over64}{a^2\over (a+1)^2}(2-4\cos 2x+ 1+\cos4x)\right)+O(x^6)$$
$$ = \sqrt{1+a} - \sqrt{1+a}\left({1\over4}{a\over a+1} + {1\over16}{a^2\over (a+1)^2}\right)(1-\cos2x) +\sqrt{1+a} + {1\over64}{a^2\over (a+1)^2}(1-\cos4x)+O(x^6)$$
$$ = \sqrt{1+a} - \sqrt{1+a}\left({1\over4}{a\over a+1} + {1\over16}{a^2\over (a+1)^2}\right)\left({4x^2\over2!}-{16x^4\over4!}\right)$$
$$ + {\sqrt{1+a}\over64}{a^2\over (a+1)^2}\left({16x^2\over2!}-{256x^4\over4!}\right)+O(x^6)$$
$$ = \sqrt{1+a} - {\sqrt{1+a}\over4}{a\over a+1}x^2 + {\sqrt{1+a}\over4!}\left({4a\over a+1} - {3a^2\over (a+1)^2}\right)x^4+O(x^6).$$

Comment: @Yuru Negometyanov In the case where $a<<1$ would $\sqrt{1+a\cos^{2}(x)}\approx 1+\frac{a}{2}\cos^{2}(x)$ be a reasonable approximation?

Comment: @Feyn_example Such assumptions do not correspond to the statement of the problem. The series should not depend on the parameter at all.

Comment: I understand that it is not technically a series expansion, but can one do a series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and then replace $x$ with $a\cos^{2}(x)$ if $a$ is small enough? Alternatively, what if one treated the function as a function of $a$ rather than $x$, i.e. $f(a)=\sqrt{1+a\cos^{2}(x)}$ for fixed $x$?

Comment: @Feyn_example Maclaurin series must correspond with series obtained by derivations calculations. And $f(a)=\sqrt{1+a\cos^2x} = 1+{1\over2}a\cos^2x-{1\over8}\cos^4x.$